# jquery what does command mean $()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working with jquery for several month and now I'm reading some program
with this command and I don't understand what does it mean, any idea?

```
myObj.$().trigger('name');
```

what does it mean `$()`?

is it like doc ready?

Comment: See [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-somefunction-the-first-pair-of-parentheses)

Comment: Where did you get the variable `myObj`?

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak-can you please add the right answer from the post as answer in SO,maybe other people will learn from it here...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is lacking critical information to answer the question. (Specifically, what is `myObj`)

Comment: @Cerbrus-myObj is object that get button...

Comment: @JohnJerrby: Yea, that really means nothing to us. ___How___ do you assign that `myObj` variable? What does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what `myObj` is and where `myObj.$().trigger("name")` is found. In the past, I've seen similar methods where an object (say a `view` or `controller` within an MV* framework) has a `$()` method associated with it.

The call to `$()` might return a `jQuery` wrapped element associated with the `view` (either constructed by the framework or assigned during initialization by the dev).

Comment: Instead of answering a question like this with a guess what might be going on, how about asking for clarification, first? `myObj` can be _anything_. And I've yet to see something return a jQuery function as described in the OP.

Answer (score -2):

The $ in the code above is just a shorter, more convenient name for the jQuery function. When you call the $() function and pass a selector to it, you create a new jQuery object.

also, 
`(function($) {
    // here $ would be point to jQuery object
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pass').keyup( ... );
    });
})(jQuery);`

allows you to use the $ inside of the ready function.

Comment: Look at the question! The `$` is a property of `myObj`. you don't know what `myObj` _is_. It could be _anything_.

Answer (score -2):

$() helps in DOM Selection Ie it would return the DOM objects that have the same identification provided as the argument to the call.

ie `$('.row')` would return all the dom objects that have the class name row simmilarly we can use # for ids and we can also get the current object by passing `'this'` as argument eg . `$(this)`. however the answers can be more helpful if you specify that what does myobj refers to in your code.

Comment: Same comment as on _all_ the other answers: Look at the question! The `$` is a property of `myObj`. you don't know what `myObj` _is_. It could be _anything_.

Comment: Besides, this really doesn't answer the question what `$()` is in the first place. How did this get upvoted?